# how i can do this in c#

Tags: c#, frameworks

I want to make a framework who the style of function calling is different from the c# style

like the instance create like

```
Documment doc= new Document("required param is here");

doc("otherinfo").Dothis();
```

dothis function calling on the basis of information who user passed when they create a new instance and otherinfo they passed latter.

well it's something like jQuery. like `$("#goo").length`

are this possible to do this in c#

Comment: Would `doc["otherinfo"].DoThis();` be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can get that exact syntax, but you can come very close:

```
Document doc = Document.Generator("required parameter");
doc("params").DoThis();
```

Document has to be a delegate type that returns a helper type that encapsulates the parameter.

```
Document doc = new Document("required parameter");
doc["params"].DoThis();
```

Document is a normal class with a default indexer that returns a helper type.

Comment: show me the code then i can do that

Comment: @Ian: For which one?  But it's late here and I'm going to bed.  Probably someone else will help you, if not then I'll do it in the morning.

Comment: i thing you have night with moonlight but i have sunlight in my country. well thanks for help.

Comment: @Ian: Check out Marc Gravell's answer, he explores the indexer idea a little further.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that what you're asking for is possible without some syntactic changes to C#.

Answer (score 1):

It almost sounds like you want currying, but for a class:

```
private Func<string,Document> CurryNewDocument(string first)
{
    return second => new Document(first, second);
}


var factory = CurryNewDocument("required param is here");

Document doc = factory("other info");
doc.DoThis();
```

If creation doesn't need to happen this way, look into [`Delegates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28VS.80%29.aspx). Delegates allow you to assign a method matching a specific method signature to a variable. In fact, `Func<string,Document>` above is a generic delegate.

Answer (score 1):

In C# and indexer has `obj[args]` syntax, so you could write something like:

```
public SomeTypeOfYours this[string query]
{ get { return ...(implementation)... } }
```

then the caller can access `doc["whatever"].SomeMethod(...)`, where `SomeMethod` is defined on `SomeTypeOfYours`. The string to `new Document("abc")` is just a constructor parameter, so:

```
public Document(string paramName) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

uh...

```
//class called document
    public class document
    {
    //constructor for the class
    public document(string s)
    {

    }

    public void dothis()
    {
    //dothis method.
    }
    }

Try that?
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call function of doc, doc("second") is not valid  something along the order of doc.get("second").dothis(); may be valid, it depends on what functions are available in a "document" object.

Answer (score 0):

I think Extension methods are a possibility in this case, but not very sure!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to achieve what JavaScript offers through it's framework, but with C#, you won't be able to do this.

Even if, current implementation of C# allowed it, there would be some kind of ambiguity in distinguishing what is a function call and what is object re-instantiating.

```
doc("second")
```

would be ambiguous.